# Recursive statement with linq

Tags: c#, recursion, linq

I have a recursive statement that removes`activities` that don't have a `resource type` for a certain `OrganizationID`. I was wondering if there was a better way to do this where I can eliminate some of the `for loops` and use a little more `linq`

```
    private IEnumerable<SubProjectDto> GetProjectAndActivitiesForByOrg(IEnumerable<SubProjectDto> children, Guid? organiazaitonId)
    {
        var subProjects = new List<SubProjectDto>();
        subProjects.AddRange(children);
        for (var i = 0; i < subProjects.Count; i++)
        {

            var activities = new List<ActivityDto>();
            activities.AddRange(subProjects[i].Activities);
            for (var j = 0; j < activities.Count; j++)
            {
                var resourceTypesForOrgs = activities[j].ActivityPersons.Where(x => x.ResourceType.OrganizationId == organiazaitonId).Count();

                if (resourceTypesForOrgs == 0)
                    activities.Remove(activities[j]);
            }

            subProjects[i].Activities = activities;

            if (subProjects[i].Children.Any())
                GetProjectAndActivitiesForByOrg(subProjects[i].Children, organiazaitonId);

        }
        children = subProjects;
        return children;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my attempt. I assume, LINQ-method based approach is allowed by your problem statement.

I have not tested the code, so please cover it by unit test(s) which you may already have.
Also, please notice that this is **not a pure function** in the functional sense of this term. It means, the method changes the state of the arguments passed in (which may or may not be desirable in different scenarios).

```
private IEnumerable<SubProjectDto> GetProjectAndActivitiesForByOrg(IEnumerable<SubProjectDto> children, Guid? organiazaitonId)
{
    return children.Select(childSubProject =>
    {
        childSubProject.Activities.RemoveAll(activity =>
                activity.ActivityPersons.All(person => person.ResourceType.OrganizationId != organiazaitonId));

        // if (childSubProject.Children.Any()) // UPD: This check is not really required
        GetProjectAndActivitiesForByOrg(childSubProject.Children, organiazaitonId);

        return childSubProject;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you.I did have to make a slight adjustment but this worked quite well!

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense actually, you can even remove the line `if (childSubProject.Children.Any())`  since `childSubProject.Children` is guaranteed to be not null as I understand. That will make it one line shorter... (I updated the answer)